# Is there any other market like stock market

Tags: stocks, stock-markets

Is there any other market like stock market where people each other buy or sell something? Where sellers also buy and buyers also sell at same palace.

Comment: eBay? Etsy? Craigslist? Facebook market?

Comment: This question is not about finance.

Comment: Farmers market? Fish market? Smithfield?

Answer (score 1):

A  stock market such as NYSE or Nasdaq is an organized exchange where there are rules usually on the characteristics of the products being traded, trading mechanics, information flow, settlement, and custody. There is a middle-man between the trading parties to reduce the counter-party risk in most of the organized exchanges.

There are many organized exchanges all over the world for commodities (LME, CBOT, etc), debt instruments, or currencies in addition to stocks. However, unlike stocks, the spot/cash trading for the other categories above, especially for debt instruments and currencies, usually takes place in over-the-counter (OTC) markets in which there are much fewer pre-set rules than in organized exchanges and usually no middle-man. (See [this article](https://www.imf.org/external/pubs/ft/fandd/basics/markets.htm) by the IMF for more on organized exchanges vs OTC markets.) Yet, financial products such as the derivatives (futures, options, etc.), based on spot prices of the products in any of the categories above, including stocks, are frequently traded through organized exchanges.

Nowadays, the same organization frequently provides organized exchanges for more than one of the categories above or multiple organizations, each providing an organized exchange in one of the categories above, are owned by the same group (CME, ICE, Deutsche Börse, LSEG).